# How to click the hyperlink (<a> tag) in Internet Explorer through Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to click the hyperlink (`<a>` tag) 'abc' in Internet Explorer through Excel VBA.

I tried getElementbyTag/getElementsbyName/getElementsbyClassName.

`<a href = 'xyz'> abc </a>`

```vb
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
set objIE = New InternetExplorer
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("xyz").Click
```

Comment: `getElementbyTag("xyz").Click`

Comment: no not worked ..runtime error

Comment: It's `getElementsbyTagName()` - some basic googling needed here

Comment: oops !! used the right syntax but still runtime error '438'

Comment: `getElementsByTagName("xyz")` would find "<xyz>" tags. As the title talks about clicking an "<a>" tag then is "xyz" the id, a class or some other attribute of the "<a>" tag you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of links, so you need to loop over and find the one you want.

```
Dim l

For Each l in objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If l.innerText = "abc" Then
        l.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next l
```